# Install PC drivers silently

Tags: batch

I have a batch file to execute the installation/update PC drivers in the same folder of the drivers stored. Is it possible to add /passive /norestart script to run them silently ?

```
for /r "%~dp0." %%a in (*.exe) do %%~fa
```

[image]

Comment: Add `/passive /norestart` at the end of your script. Whether the driver installers honour those switches depends entirely on the programs themselves.

Comment: I tried but it seems not honor !

Comment: Then the programs may simply not have silent modes, or you have to google the particular switches for the specific drivers. For example https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=silent+driver+installer+intel gives `-s` [for Intel drivers](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000008116/graphics.html). `-silent`, `/silent`, `/quiet`, `/q` are all options I've seen over the years. These options are by no means guaranteed to be supported and we have no idea what drivers you have.